# Is there a way to append data in distributed Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

I am using distributed TensorFlow not to distribute the network, but to distribute the work.

With distributed TensorFlow we get framework to distribute the work and a communication between the workers for the status. This lighted weighted communication protocol, inbuilt recovery and device selection for specific task makes me to try and use distributed tensorFlow to build multiple micro models in parallel.

So in my code this is what I am doing.

```
def main(_): 
    #some global data block
    a = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2))
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" %server.server_def.task_index,cluster=server.server_def.cluster)):
        #some ops to keep the cluster alive 
        var = tf.Variable(initial_value=10, name='var')
        op = tf.assign_add(var,10)
        xx = tf.placeholder("float")
        yy = tf.reduce_sum(xx)
        #start monitoring session 
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,is_chief=is_chief) as mon_sess:
        mon_sess.run(op)
        #distribute data
        inputs = a[:,server.server_def.task_index]
        #start a local session in worker 
        sess = tf.Session()
        sum_value = sess.run(yy,feed_dict={xx:inputs})
        sess.close()
```

After every workers work is completed I want to append some information to 
a variable in global network. (As we are not able to update global variables like `a` in the above example, I want to make use of `mon_sess` to update global network.

I want keep appending some tensors (o/p of each workers) and make `chief` to read and write it out. 
Is there a way to do this ?

And please update if you see any problems in the above approach.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I tired this and able to get the updates from local workers information to global network

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import time
def main(server, log_dir, context):
    #create a random array
    a = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2))
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" %server.server_def.task_index,cluster=server.server_def.cluster)):
        var = tf.Variable(initial_value=10, name='var')
        op = tf.assign_add(var,10)
        xx = tf.placeholder("float")
        yy = tf.reduce_sum(xx)
        concat_init = tf.Variable([0],dtype=tf.float32)
        sum_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        concat_op = tf.concat([concat_init,sum_holder],0)
        assign_op = tf.assign(concat_init,concat_op,validate_shape=False)
    is_chief = server.server_def.task_index == 0
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,is_chief=is_chief) as mon_sess:
        mon_sess.run(op)
        print (a)
        print ("reading my part")
        inputs = a[:,server.server_def.task_index]
        print(inputs)
        sess = tf.Session()
        sum_value = sess.run(yy,feed_dict={xx:inputs})
        print(sum_value)
        mon_sess.run(assign_op,feed_dict={sum_holder:[sum_value]})
        if is_chief:
            time.sleep(5)
            worker_sums = mon_sess.run(assign_op,feed_dict={sum_holder:[0]})
            print (worker_sums)
        sess.close()
        if is_chief:
            while True:
                pass
```